# Structure Map dependency injection issue : No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined

Tags: visual-studio, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5, structuremap, dependency-inversion

I just added the structureMap from nuget and modified the DefaultRegistry file like this

public class DefaultRegistry : Registry {
            #region Constructors and Destructors

```
        public DefaultRegistry() {
            Scan(
                scan => {
                    // scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                    scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory(
                     filter => filter.FullName.StartsWith("TaskManagement"));

                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
                });
            //For<IExample>().Use<Example>();
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Controller code is

```
 namespace TaskManagement.TaskStatus 
        {
            public class TaskStatusController : Controller
            {
                private readonly IGetTaskStatusList _query;
                public TaskStatusController(IGetTaskStatusList query)
                {
                    _query = query;
                }
                // GET: TaskStatus
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                    var TaskStatus = _query.Execute();
                    return View(TaskStatus);
                }
            }
        }
```

Exception which I am getting 
StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException: 'No default Instance is registered and cannot be automatically determined for type 'Application.TaskStatus.IGetTaskStatusList'

```
There is no configuration specified for Application.TaskStatus.IGetTaskStatusList

1.) new TaskStatusController(*Default of IGetTaskStatusList*)
2.) TaskManagement.TaskStatus.TaskStatusController
3.) Instance of TaskManagement.TaskStatus.TaskStatusController
4.) Container.GetInstance(TaskManagement.TaskStatus.TaskStatusController)
```

Answer (score 0):

my interface and the class is in other project ; so there are two ways to resolve this issue. We can use either of these to resolve this.

1. `scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();`
2. `For<IGetTaskStatusList>().Use<GetTaskStatusList>();`

Example :

```
public DefaultRegistry() {
         Scan ( scan => {
                    scan.TheCallingAssembly();
                  //scan.AssembliesFromApplicationBaseDirectory();
                    scan.WithDefaultConventions();
                    scan.With(new ControllerConvention());
              });
        For<IGetTaskStatusList>().Use<GetTaskStatusList>();
}
```